# python multi-thread timing

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to get a hold of multi-threading in Python.
I wrote this snippet of code:

```
import requests
import threading
from time import time,sleep

start_time = time()

class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,threadID,name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name


     def run(self):
        print(self.name + " Starting")
        start = time()

        url = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
        for i in range(20):
            res = requests.post(url,timeout=5)
        end = time()
        print("Final Thread Time: " + str(end-start) + 'For Thread {}'.format(self.threadID))





  threads = []
  threadID = 1

  for i in range(1,5):
        thread = myThread(threadID,'thread{}'.format(threadID))
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
        threadID += 1
  for t in threads:
      t.join()
  final_time_end = time()
  print("Final Time: " + str(start_time - final_time_end))
```

So basically it's sending 20 post requests to a url in each thread.
The result is:

```
Final Thread Time: 6.0695300102 For Thread 3
Final Thread Time: 6.8553800583 For Thread 1
Final Thread Time: 6.9735219479 For Thread 5
Final Thread Time: 6.5822350979 For Thread 4
Final Thread Time: 11.330765152 For Thread 2
```

I have a dual core CPU,what I don't understand is why almost each time I run this script,4 threads finish at nearly same time(6s),but 1 thread takes about 11s(btw sometimes they all finish at the same time).

This happens when I run this code with 4 or 3 threads as well.the last one usually takes more time to finish.
What's happening in the last thread that takes more time?

Comment: That's not that hard to understand, the fifth thread to run is blocked by the previous 4, let's say you have a CPU of only 4 cores, so the first four run first, the fifth is blocked and will only kick off after the first round of 4 threads are done. So the last one takes more times. When I say CPU of 4, it's just for a demo.

Comment: @MenglongLi Thanks for your answer, I have only 2 cores.
What I expect is the second round of threads finish later as well,not only the fifth one.

Comment: yeah, that's the point, your CPU has 2 cores may work as 4 cores by virtual tech.

Comment: What if each request is to a different website?  I am wondering if the site you're making the requests to is throttling you.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I tried it on different websites,results are usually like this

Comment: Did you try making one request to each of N websites?  Or just changed to make all N requests to 1 site?